# if html has several input with same name, python how to receive

Tags: python, html

Question: in html there is a loop , for each cycle, there is  an input with name="answer[]". What I want to do is to receive all data from input in python, My way is "answer=request.form["answer[]"]", however, it only receives the first answer. What should I write to receive all answers from html.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>fill_out page </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> answer page </h1>
<Form method="POST">
{% for question in content %}
Question{{  loop.index  }} : &ensp; &ensp; {{   question    }}<br></br>
<input name="answer[]" placeholder="Enter your answer"/><br></br>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" name="bt">submit</button><br></br>
</Form>
<h2> if you want to switch account <a href="./index.html"> resign in</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

python:

```
@app.route("/fill_out.html/<username>",methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/fill_out.html",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def fill_out(username=None) :
    content=find_question()
    if request.method=="POST" :
        answer=request.form["answer[]"]
        print(answer)
        return redirect(url_for("congratulations",username=username))
    return render_template("fill_out.html",content=content)
```

If you can help, I really appreciate

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the website **do** tell you why you couldn't post it!

Comment: It is not about why I can not post, the sentences are just "context" the problem is python

Comment: Please describe more precisely what the code sould do.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you for reminding me

Comment: A helpful addition would be for you to post the rendered html here (from the actual web page). It may be that you are not getting rendered what you expect.

Comment: Rendering is working correctly. I know if I can make name unique , then it is working. Your suggestion to do that is "name="answer"+loop.index"?

Comment: I did some research and it seems like technically the name="answer[]" should work - but that maybe some frameworks don't handle it well. So you are saying it works now if you make it unique?

Comment: like you I thought "answer[]" should work from google, but it did not. I try your way <input name="answer[{{ loop.index0 }}]" placeholder="Enter your answer"/><br></br> something like that , and in python i just use answer.append(request.form["answer[0]"]) 
answer.append(request.form["answer[1]"]) and it works

Comment: hi man how to mark you as accepted answer? The FAQ says " checkmark"  where the checkmark is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually best to post your problem as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's easy for others to reporduce. In your case that could look like this:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

template = """
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>fill_out page </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> answer page </h1>
<Form method="POST">
{% for question in content %}
Question{{  loop.index  }} : &ensp; &ensp; {{   question    }}<br></br>
<input name="answer[]" placeholder="Enter your answer"/><br></br>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" name="bt">submit</button><br></br>
</Form>
<h2> if you want to switch account <a href="./index.html"> resign in</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
"""

@app.route("/fill_out.html/<username>",methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/fill_out.html",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def fill_out(username=None) :
    if request.method=="POST" :
        return render_template_string("Result: <pre>{{form}}</pre>",
                                      form=request.form)
    return render_template_string(template,content=["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you run this (from a file or by pasting it in an interactive interpreter session), you'll see how the returned [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.form) looks, e.g:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('bt', ''),
                    ('answer[]', 'A1'),
                    ('answer[]', 'A2'),
                    ('answer[]', 'A3')])
```

It's a [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) with one entry for each field of the form, three of them having the same name `answer[]`. There is nothing special about the `[]`, it's just part of the form field name. It's perfectly valid for a html form to contain multiple elements with the same name, and adding a `[]` isn't needed (it's a PHP idiom which causes php to create an array of all submitted values, but we're talking about python here, so best forget about it.). You could have called your elements simply `answer` and it wouldn't make a difference.

Long story short, if you want all submitted answers as a list, use:

```
answers = request.form.getlist('answer[]')
```

Then you can use `answers[0]` or similar to index, or loop over the list. You explicitly need to say you want a list (the above mentioned PHP idiom can cause problems when one assumes to work with a string but then gets passed an array).

If you only want the first answer, you can use either of:

```
answer = request.form.get('answer[]')
answer = request.form['answer[]']
```

If no key with the name `answer[]` exists `getlist()` returns `[]`, `get()` returns `None` and indexing raises an exception.